# pymssql threading

Tags: python

при попытке забрать таблицы при помощи потоков вылетает ошибка
Код проги:

```py
import time
import threading
import warnings
import pandas as pd
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import pymssql 
from config import ConfigAxapta

class CustomThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, func, args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.func = func
        self.args = args

    def run(self):
        self.func(*self.args)


class Axapta:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def connector(self, database, user,
                  password, host):
        mssql_conn = pymssql.connect(server=host,
                                     user=user,
                                     password=password,
                                     database=database
                                     )
        return mssql_conn

    def run(self, field, conn):
        # try:
        table = pd.read_sql(field, conn)
        # except Exception:
            # print(f'Something wet wrong, host')
            # table = pd.DataFrame()
        # return table


def main():
    kwargs = {
        'database': ConfigAxapta.DATABASE,
        'user': ConfigAxapta.USER,
        'password': ConfigAxapta.PASSWORD,
        'host': ConfigAxapta.HOST,
    }
    field = ConfigAxapta.REQUEST
    connect = Axapta().connector(**kwargs)
    threads_list = []
    for table in ConfigAxapta.TABLES:
        print(f'Starting download table: {table}')
        t = CustomThread(func=Axapta().run, args=[field+table, connect])
        threads_list.append(t)
        t.start()
        print(f'end download table: {table}')

    for j in threads_list:
        j.join()

    connect.close()
    print('closed connect')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    main()
    duration_time  = time.time() - start_time
    print(f'{duration_time}sec')
```

Сама ошибка:

```
Starting download table: INVENTITEMRATINGDISHCATEGORYTRANS
end download table: INVENTITEMRATINGDISHCATEGORYTRANS
Starting download table: DIRPARTYTABLE
end download table: DIRPARTYTABLE
Starting download table: HRMDEPARTMENTDAYPLANINCOME
end download table: HRMDEPARTMENTDAYPLANINCOME
Starting download table: HCMWORKER
end download table: HCMWORKER
Starting download table: DIRPERSONNAME
end download table: DIRPERSONNAME
Starting download table: USERINFO
end download table: USERINFO
Starting download table: DIRPERSONUSER
end download table: DIRPERSONUSER
Starting download table: HCMWORKERTITLE
end download table: HCMWORKERTITLE
Starting download table: RPAYHISTORY
end download table: RPAYHISTORY
Starting download table: HCMTITLE
end download table: HCMTITLE
Starting download table: HCMTITLESET
end download table: HCMTITLESET
Starting download table: HCMTITLESETMEMBER
end download table: HCMTITLESETMEMBER
Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 20, in run
    self.func(*self.args)
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 39, in run
    table = pd.read_sql(field, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 380, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1469, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Exception in thread Thread-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 20, in run
    self.func(*self.args)
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 39, in run
    table = pd.read_sql(field, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 380, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1469, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 20, in run
    self.func(*self.args)
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 39, in run
    table = pd.read_sql(field, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 380, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1469, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
Exception in thread Thread-12:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 20, in run
    self.func(*self.args)
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 39, in run
    table = pd.read_sql(field, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 380, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1469, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 20, in run
    self.func(*self.args)
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 39, in run
    table = pd.read_sql(field, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 380, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1469, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 20, in run
    self.func(*self.args)
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 39, in run
    table = pd.read_sql(field, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 380, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1469, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Exception in thread Thread-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 20, in run
    self.func(*self.args)
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 39, in run
    table = pd.read_sql(field, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 380, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1469, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 20, in run
    self.func(*self.args)
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 39, in run
    table = pd.read_sql(field, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 380, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1469, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable


Exception in thread Thread-11:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 20, in run
    self.func(*self.args)
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 39, in run
    table = pd.read_sql(field, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 380, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1469, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 20, in run
    self.func(*self.args)
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 39, in run
    table = pd.read_sql(field, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 380, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1469, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/pymssql.pyx", line 448, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1064, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1096, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1294, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.get_result
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1639, in _mssql.check_cancel_and_raise
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1683, in _mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException
_mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (20003, b'DB-Lib error message 20003, severity 6:\nAdaptive Server connection timed out\nOperating System error during Operation timed out (60)\n')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1431, in execute
    cur.execute(*args)
  File "src/pymssql.pyx", line 468, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
pymssql.OperationalError: (20003, b'DB-Lib error message 20003, severity 6:\nAdaptive Server connection timed out\nOperating System error during Operation timed out (60)\n')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 20, in run
    self.func(*self.args)
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 39, in run
    table = pd.read_sql(field, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 380, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1468, in read_query
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1445, in execute
    raise_with_traceback(ex)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 420, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1431, in execute
    cur.execute(*args)
  File "src/pymssql.pyx", line 468, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM HCMWORKER': (20003, b'DB-Lib error message 20003, severity 6:\nAdaptive Server connection timed out\nOperating System error during Operation timed out (60)\n')


Exception in thread Thread-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 20, in run
    self.func(*self.args)
  File "test/axapta_db.py", line 39, in run
    table = pd.read_sql(field, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 380, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1469, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable


closed connect
0.22869396209716797sec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте в каждом потоке своё собственное, отдельное соединение к базе

```
    mssql_conn = pymssql.connect(server=host,
                                 user=user,
                                 password=password,
                                 database=database
                                 )
```

Насколько я знаю, любой модуль работы с базами данных будет глючить в таких условиях, как в Вашем примере.

Либо, если хотите оставить как есть, то используйте `Lock`, чтобы блокировать запрос к БД другими потоками, пока один его использует. Правда, в этом случае пропадает весь смысл многопоточности в Вашем решении